# How to create and set properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, properties

I have 2 projects. in One project i am setting a 'view' and using requestView() i get the information such as transformation
matrix and visibility.

In the second project i have been told that i need to create a 'View' object and add the properties to set the things i get from 
the 1st project (matrix and visibility).

I am not sure what this means.

I create a file called View.js and added properties {} which i was told will only take float[] for now.

```
properties: {
                /**
                 * TranformMatrix
                 */
                TransformMatrix: {
                    type: "float[]"
                },

                /**
                 * Visibility
                 */
                Visibility: {
                    type: "float[]"
                }
            }
```

is this all i need to do?
for properties what do set methods look like in my case?
what other work would be required?

In this second project i was told i cant just use setMatrix it will be something like applyMatrix and this takes the format of the 1st projects transform matrix (4*4) and applys this matrix using three js method which i think is 'object.applyMatrix"

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm wrong, but  I'm not sure how _type: "float[]"_ is going to prevent someone to do something. Something is missing? TypeScript?  ecmascript 2017?  I feel like it is time to go and have some sleep.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question :) but thanks